# How to run background JS on two pages of Active Tab in Chrome Extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to discover if it is possible to run JavaScript on next page of active link on Chrome Extension.

For example, I have an a link at **current active tab** ans **Page A** like:

`<a id="next"  href="domain.com/1.html/">Next Page But Same Active Tab</a>`

and in Page B of current active tab again:

`<a id="prev" href="domain.com/2.html/">Previous Page But Same Active Tab Again</a>`

So can I run a code like this:

```
 $('#next').get(0).click();

    setTimeout(function(){ 

        $('#prev').get(0).click();

    }, 10000);
```

technically like running JS on Current and Next page?

Comment: Your background script needs to run a *content script* on the first page to click the link, wait for the second page to load, run another content script to click the link. I've seen several examples on StackOverflow, try searching.

Comment: Thanks for comment wOxxOm , I am actually running the script on `content.js` and I thought can wait for next page fully uploaded by setting the `setTimeout()`. I was not lucky however to find even close samples here and on google